# Is it possible to use template with operator overload in C++?

Tags: c++

Is it possible to use `template` together with operator overload (not using template together with the class, but only with the specific operator such as `operator[]`) in C++?

Here is an example (of course it can not be compiled pass).

```cpp
class myClass
{
    ....
    template<int i> auto operator[](std::string) -> std::tuple_element_t<t, types>
    {
        //some code here
    }
    ...
}
int main()
{
    myClass myObject;
    ....
    auto a = myObject["rabbit"]<1>;
    auto b = myObject["dog"]<2>;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, but the way you call it has to change.  In order to specify the template parameter of `operator[]` you need to call it with member function syntax like

```
myObject.operator[]<1>("rabbit");
```

Which really isn't very nice to look at.  Instead, you could just use a named member function like `get` and then use it like

```
class myClass
{
    ....
    template<int i> auto get(std::string) -> std::tuple_element_t<t, types>
    {
        //some code here
    }
    ...
}

auto a = myObject.get<1>("rabbit");
```